# Erro em calculo de execução

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho a seguinte questão.

Eu tenho esses seguintes tempos obtidos através do `Stopwatch`, onde foi colocado dentro de um método para retornar o saldo de banco de horas do funcionário. Só que ele está me mostrando um tempo totalmente contraditório com o que foi calculado pelos `Stopwatch`.

Dentro do método foi divido em 7 partes para ver onde seria o motivo de levar tanto tempo.

Resultado:

Dados que foram retornado do banco de horas pelo método: `-82:52:24;`

> 1 - Tempo para pegar 1ª marcação: 00:00:00.0137141;
>   2 - Tempo de calculo do saldo: 00:00:00.0153916;
>   3 - Tempo para pegar todas as marcações: 00:00:00.0008668;
>   4 - Tempo para formatar data/hora:00:00:00.0013553;
>   5 - Tempo para setar Informações:00:00:00.0015071;
>   6 - Tempo para alimentar saldo:00:00:00.0005936;
>   7 - Tempo para juntar tudo e mostrar o resultado: 00:00:00.0000051;
>   8 - Tempo Total do método:**00:00:17.3199664**

Gostaria de saber como é possível o resultado de 1 à 7 levar esses 17 seg que foi informado
pelo calculo da soma de todos os tempos.

Ex:

```
private string CalculaSaldo(FUNCIONARIOS funcionario, DateTime ultimoDia, TimeSpan cargaHoraria, TimeSpan tempoAlmoco, int diaTrabalho)
{
  #region 1
      Stopwatch1.Start();
      //CÓDIGO ...
      Stopwatch1.Stop();
  #endregion

  #region 2
     Stopwatch2.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch2.Stop();
  #endregion

  #region 3
     Stopwatch3.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch3.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 4
     Stopwatch4.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch4.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 5
     Stopwatch5.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch5.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 6
     Stopwatch6.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch6.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 7
     Stopwatch7.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch7.Stop();
   #endregion

   long total = Stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + Stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds + Stopwatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds + Stopwatch4.ElapsedMilliseconds +
            Stopwatch5.ElapsedMilliseconds + Stopwatch6.ElapsedMilliseconds + Stopwatch7.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   return result + ";tempo total: " + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(total).ToString();
}
```

Todos os pontos o método foi separado com um Stopwatch.

Obg.

Comment: Por favor, poste um exemplo do código que está a utilizar para realizar o cálculo.

Comment: A variavel que guarda o tempo total podera' nao estar 00:00:00 no inicio, mas como referido pelo @Renan, sem codigo nao e' facil

Comment: Isso acontece na primeira vez que esse método é acessado. Ele só é inciado dentro do método. E está dando um resultado absurdo.

Comment: Qual é o valor da variável `long total` ao final do seu código?

Comment: Na verdade... o retorno não foi 17 milissegundos?

Comment: Eu testei esse codigo numa console application e funciona bem, tente fazer debug e ver quais os tempos que Os stopWatch's tem mesmo antes de retornar o result.

Comment: Retorno atual da long deu 17059

Comment: E quais sao os ElapsedMilliseconds individuais de cada um?

Comment: Está no código acima que passei.
1 - 0137141;
2 - 0153916;
3 - 0008668;
4 - 0013553;
5 - 0015071;
6 - 0005936;
7 - 0000051;

Comment: @Rsouza, sua pergunta ainda está confusa. Os tempos 1 a 7 também foram obtidos a partir de TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Stopwatch#.ElapsedMilliseconds)? Qual a relevância do resultado real da função para sua pergunta?

Comment: @korbes Os resultados foram obtidos atravez do codigo que coloquei. O TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Stopwatch#.ElapsedMilliseconds) é para somar o resultado do long.

Comment: Cada `StopWatch` é uma instância separada mesmo? Não tem dois ou mais apontando pro mesmo objeto não? Coloca o código que os cria.

Comment: @RSouza, coloca todo o código da função, só tirando as partes do seu cálculo de banco de horas.

Comment: O problema seria na soma msm do valor, o codigo nesse caso não é necessário pq eu tenho o tempo que cada um leva para ser executado. Onde tem "//CÓDIGO" que fica o código do meu método, e ele fica entre o seu medidor de tempo que quando somado ele gera uma valor contraditório. Vou tentar resolver de outro jeito caso não haja outro jeito.

Comment: @Rsouza, então os Stopwatch# são membros da classe? Pode estar ocorrendo concorrência na chamada do método?

Comment: Eu não entendi o que significa "Dados que foram retornado do banco de horas pelo método": de onde vem esse valor? aliás, está correto um valor negativo?

Comment: Outra coisa (em relação ao seu comentário em resposta ao Joao): tem certeza que esses valores individuais de `ElapsedMilliseconds` estão corretos? Por exemplo, 137141 milisegundos são 137,141 segundos (por volta de 2 minutos e 17 segundos, ou "00:02:17.1410000"). Isso *não é* a mesma coisa que "00:00:00.0137141" (13,7141 milisegundos).

Answer (score 1):

voce não esta resetando o Stopwatch apenas parando e iniciando novamente e o ultimo tempo ira ficar com a soma de todos os outros. Ex: o segundo ira ficar com a soma do primeiro e o tempo dele mesmo

Comment: Isso acontece na primeira vez que esse método é acessado. Ele só é inciado dentro do método. E está dando um resultado absurdo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer deste modo.

```
private string CalculaSaldo(FUNCIONARIOS funcionario, DateTime ultimoDia, TimeSpan cargaHoraria, TimeSpan tempoAlmoco, int diaTrabalho)
{
StopwatchTOTAL.Start();
  #region 1
      Stopwatch1.Start();
      //CÓDIGO ...
      Stopwatch1.Stop();
  #endregion

  #region 2
     Stopwatch2.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch2.Stop();
  #endregion

  #region 3
     Stopwatch3.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch3.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 4
     Stopwatch4.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch4.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 5
     Stopwatch5.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch5.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 6
     Stopwatch6.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch6.Stop();
   #endregion

   #region 7
     Stopwatch7.Start();
     //CÓDIGO ...
     Stopwatch7.Stop();
   #endregion
StopwatchTOTAL.Stop();

   long total = StopwatchTOTAL.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   return result + ";tempo total: " + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(total).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Também já tentei desse jeito Paulo e deu a mesma coisa ! o0' muito estranho esse resultado.

Comment: Imagino que, por mais que possa ser uma diferença negligível, o `StopwatchTOTAL` vai acabar gravando o tempo utilizado pelas funções Start/Stop dos demais.

Comment: Sim @Conrad, mais isso seria algo irrisório que nem duraria 100 milissegundos.